# Storing string as it in php

Tags: php, c++, string

I am taking input from a html page then data comes to php page and is stored in a variable say $code. The problem is when i submit :-

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main( ) {
    cout<<"1";
    }
```

Then what stored in $code is :-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( ) {
cout<<\"1\";          //Notice the change , these backslashes at cout.
}
```

How can i avoid this ? i am using 000webhost.com & this thing doesnt happens in my localhost.

Comment: Is this a new version of php? lol

Comment: [Magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?

Comment: @Kaii: Is it **that** difficult to you guys to understand that it's a string that contains C++ code or you're trying to win "the worst clown" cup?

Comment: sorry it was my bad .. i misread ...  apologize

Comment: @zerkms : LoL , well said. 
Will Heredocs solve my problem?

Comment: @Kriti Saxena: nope, the correct way is to turn off magic quotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because the quotes are escaped so this dosent happen:
Say you are storing "apple"
if the quotes were not escaped this would happen

```
$var = ""apple"";
```

causing an error while this works:

```
$var = "\"apple\"";
```

You can use `stripslashes();` to get rid of the forward slashes if you plan to echo the data I think.

Comment: Terrible advice. You need to fix the root, not the consequences. -1

Comment: Well I assumed they couldn't fix the problem because of 000webhost sorry. But if they do have access to that just disable magicquotes in php.ini.

Comment: @lemondrop than try http://www.ramnode.com/ its very cheap .. and you can try stuff

Comment: lemondrop , thanks :D 
It worked :*

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution
In your php.ini file, odds are that the magic_quotes_gpc directive is set to on. This should be disabled for security reasons. If you don't have access to the php.ini file (eg. on a shared host), you can always accomplish the same using an .htaccess directive (assuming this is an apache server).

In your php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

In an .htaccess file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Why is this happening?

The reason this is happening is due to the following course of logic.

A string that needs escaping is sent to the server.
This is my string. It's awesome.
Magic Quotes escapes the apostrophe before it gets to your code.
This is my string. It\'s awesome
mysql_real_escape_string now has two characters to escape, the backslash \ as well as the apostrophe \'.
This is my string. It\\'s awesome
This new super-escaped string is stored in the database.
When the string is retrieved from the database, it get's passed to stripslashes. This removes the two escapes added in step 3, but since one of the backslashes has been escaped stripslashes thinks it belongs.
This is my string. It\'s awesome
This problem can really get out of hand when you re-submit these strings to the database, as each time the number of backslashes multiplies.

Alternative Solution
A quick-and easy alternative would be to simply remove the slashes added by magic_quotes before passing the string to mysql_real_escape_string.

```
$str = stripslashes($code);
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```